# How to Type Pause/Break with the Official Raspberry Pi Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

How do you type Pause/Break on the official [Raspberry Pi Keyboard](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-keyboard-and-hub/)? It's some emulator that needs this. I've read that on some Lenovos without Pause/Break you type Fn+P and Fn+B, but that does not work on the Raspberry Pi Keyboard, e.g. Fn+P types Num Pad -, and Fn+B types b, according to **xev** (print contents of X events).

I have the UK keyboard layout (Model No: RPI-KYB).

```
RPI $ cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBMODEL=pc105
XKBLAYOUT=gb
XKBVARIANT=
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
BACKSPACE="guess"
```